# Remote SMTP (Google) in vbscript to send email via iMacros

Tags: smtp

I'm using the Scripting Edition of iMacros web testing tool, I just hope that you know it guys. And I'm trying to use the Google SMTP (smtp.gmail.com) port 465 to send an email via vbscript each time iMacros encountered error during playback. However, each time I run the script, it's giving me this error

the sendusing configuration value is invalid

I've already tried some known fixes but it's still an issue. Here's the script:

Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")

myMail.Subject="Sending email with CDO"

myMail.From="email@gmail.com"

myMail.To="email@domain.com"

myMail.TextBody="This is a message."

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _

("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2

'Name or IP of remote SMTP server

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _

("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.gmail.com"

'Server port

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _

("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=465

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

myMail.Send

set myMail=nothing

I'm using the Windows7 Home Premium. and latest version of iMacros. I hope anyone could lend a hand. Thank you so much.

Comment: Not sure if you're aware, but you cannot relay via Google's SMTP.

Comment: Hi! Brad. Thank you for your response. I'm not aware actually, I'm a complete newbie. =( I'm just following iMacros example here - http://wiki.imacros.net/send-email.vbs and http://www.iopus.com/guides/bestpopsmtp.htm. Any recommendations that you have? I also tried setting up a local SMTP server but it was not a success. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try using port 587 for the SMTP. That's what I use in my C# program.

Answer (score 0):

To use googles smtp server you must supply a user name and password to connect with as it's not an anonymous smtp server.  I have a Google apps premier account which I use to relay messages through.  I'm not sure if Google allow mail relay on a normal googlemail account though.